# Remove domain from Google's copyright infringement blacklist

Tags: seo, google, blacklist, dmca

My website lets people share subtitles, and sometimes users upload copyrighted material. Therefore, I wasn't surprised to find that google blacklisted the pages which contain copyrighted material, and I am removing those.

However, the domain `example.com` is now also blacklisted. How can I get it off the list, and let users find it via Google?

I've downloaded the copyright removals data from [Google's transparency report](https://transparencyreport.google.com/copyright/domains/subtitlecat.com), scanned through, and found that many of the removal requests aren't to pages like `example.com/disney_movie.html`, but the domain `example.com`. I also got the report from [the lumen database](https://www.lumendatabase.org/notices/18637929), same problem. I found a relevant question [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/111649/countering-a-dmca-removal-from-google-search-for-a-root-category-page), but it mentions emails where Google notifies me of a DMCA removal, but I don't have any such emails.

Comment: I edited your terminology: `.com` is a top-level domain and `example.com` is a domain.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller that's great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, type `site:example.com` into Google. If there are no results, you might be blacklisted, but if you can see a bunch of results, you're just ranking poorly.

If you still think you might be blacklisted, start by adding your website to [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/about) and looking for [Manual Actions](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9044175?hl=en).

My understanding is that the only way for a website to be actually wholesale blacklisted from Google is for a person at Google to slap it with a Manual Action.

The Manual Actions report should tell you what to do next.